# How do I change the rendered template in Flask when a thread completes?

Tags: python, multithreading, heroku, flask, backgroundworker

I have a function that crawls the web for data and computes a score for the search. However, this can take a while and sometimes the webpage times out before finishing execution.

So I created a separate thread that executes the function and `loading.html` that tells the client that data is still being collected. Once the function ends in the thread, how do I reload the webpage to display `output.html` that displays the score.

This is a simpler version of what I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def init():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def load():
    th = Thread(target=something, args=())
    th.start()
    return render_template('loading.html')

def something():
    #do some calculation and return the needed value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

How do I route my app to `render_template('output.html', x=score)`  once `something()`  inside the thread `th` finishes?

I am trying to avoid task queues like redis since I want to deploy this app on the web and I don't want to incur charges (this is more of an experiment and hobby).

A detailed answer with code would help a lot since I am new to flask and multithreading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way is making cyclic Ajax requests to a *thread_status* endpoint that gives you information about the currently running task.

```
import time
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import render_template
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)
th = Thread()
finished = False


@app.route("/")
def init():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def load():
    global th
    global finished
    finished = False
    th = Thread(target=something, args=())
    th.start()
    return render_template('loading.html')


def something():
    """ The worker function """
    global finished
    time.sleep(5)
    finished = True


@app.route('/result')
def result():
    """ Just give back the result of your heavy work """
    return 'Done'


@app.route('/status')
def thread_status():
    """ Return the status of the worker thread """
    return jsonify(dict(status=('finished' if finished else 'running')))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

So in your *loading.html* just insert a cyclic Ajax `get()` request:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var refresh_id = setInterval(function() {
            $.get(
              "{{ url_for('thread_status') }}",
              function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.status == 'finished') {
                  window.location.replace("{{ url_for('result') }}");
                }
              }
            )}
          , 1000);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can even append this by a progress counter if you like. But you need to take care that you prevent the thread from being run multiple times.

Comment: This works just like I wanted it to! Thanks! Wonder why I didn't think of writing a javascript function before